# Como enviar itens selecionado de uma Grid por e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma grid e nela possuo uma listagens de produto de vários fornecedores diferente e cada fornecedor possui o seu Id.
Gostaria de selecionar a os itens da grid e enviar o e-mail para cada fornecedor com os seus respectivos itens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo salvar os dados aprovado. Segue abaixo meu controller:

```
        public ActionResult Create(PersonOrcamentoModel model)
        {   
            Orcamento orca = new Orcamento();
            Orca_Financeiro_ADO FinanAdo = new Orca_Financeiro_ADO();
            Orcamento_ADO OrcaAdo = new Orcamento_ADO();

            foreach (var item in model.Dados)
         {          
            orca.Data = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            orca.Descricao = item.Descricao;
            orca.Fornecedor = item.Fornecedor;
            orca.Marca = item.Marca;
            orca.Modelo = item.Modelo;
            orca.Prazo = item.Prazo;
            orca.Quantidade = item.Quantidade;
            orca.Status = "Aguardando";
            orca.UnidadeMedida = item.UnidadeMedida;
            orca.Valor = item.Valor;
            orca.ValorUnitario = item.ValorUnitario;
            OrcaAdo.Inserir_Orcamento(orca);

            using (var ctx = new EstoqueDBContext())
            {
                var Dados_Id = ctx.Orcamentos.ToList().Last();
                    var p = new Orca_Financeiro
                {
                    IdFornecedor = item.IdFornecedor,
                    Data =       DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")),
                    Descricao = item.Descricao,
                    Fornecedor = item.Fornecedor,
                    Marca = item.Marca,
                    Modelo = item.Modelo,
                    Prazo = item.Prazo,
                    Quantidade = item.Quantidade,
                    Status = "Aguardando",
                    UnidadeMedida = item.UnidadeMedida,
                    Valor = item.Valor,
                    ValorUnitario = item.ValorUnitario,
                    Id_Orcamento = Dados_Id.Id

                };
                db.Orca_Financeiro.Add(p);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


      }

        //ArquivoExcel exe = new ArquivoExcel();
        //exe.WriteTsv(model.Dados.ToList());
        //enviar o e-mail aqui

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é a sua dúvida ou problema. Seria como enviar o e-mail?

Comment: Ola André, eu pretendo enviar um e-mail com uma listagem dos itens aprovado. Sendo que nessa listagem eu possuo o id do fornecedor e em alguns casos, nesta listagem pode ocorrer de ter varios fornecedores. eu pretendo enviar por exemplo um e-mail para o fornecedor de id=1 com os itens pertencentes a ele e se for id = 2 separar estes produtos deste fornecedor de id =2 e enviar separadamente.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi sua questão, seria só agrupar seus itens por IdFornecedor e enviar o e-mail.

```
        var dadosPorFornecedor = model.Dados
            .GroupBy(x => x.IdFornecedor)
            .Select(x => new {IdFornecedor=x.Key, Itens=x.ToList() });

        foreach(var item in dadosPorFornecedor)
        {
            //Pode pegar informações referente ao fornecedor
            //Aqui terei item.IdFornecedor
            foreach(var dado in item.Itens)
            {
                //Pega os itens referente a cada fornecedor
                //Aqui terei dados como dado.Descricao, dado.Marca, dado.Modelo, etc.
            }

            //Envia o e-mail montado com os dados acima.
        }
```

Comment: Funcionou como esperado. Muito obrigado André. Abraços!!!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou @AndersonMacahdo! Abraço.